# What will be the pymongo query in this case

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of information about people in different teams, and I want to find the count of the number of people in each team.

```
{"name": "something1", "team":"hr"}
{"name": "something2", "team":"backend"}
{"name": "something3", "team":"hr"}
{"name": "something4", "team":"database"}
{"name": "something5", "team":"database"}
```

I am looking for a one-liner query, I am new to this, please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use mongos aggregate command. Something along the lines of:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {"$group" : {_id:"$team", count:{$sum:1}}}
    ])
```

I hope that helps, or points you in the right direction.